# ASP.NET MVC code first, foreign key to Sharepoint table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-migrations, code-first

Maybe someone can help me with my problem:

**Problem**

I am working with ASP.NET MVC and have created a simple website with a database behind it. In this database I have different tables, but the ID of the hierarchical top table should point to a Sharepoint table. There I have my main data and my database should have a foreign key to the ID in this table. Is this possible and if so how does it work?

**Need?**

To answer the question of why I need this connection to the Sharepoint table, that is because that is the only place the data is updated and I want the data in my database to contain the new data so that when I add data to my database I can reference new IDs without having to add them manually.

Maybe someone has a hint for me or can refer to another resource which includes this information, thank you (**^▽^**)

Comment: Sharepoint isn't a database - it doesn't have "tables" ....

Comment: Yes, I know that Sharepoint is not a database. In my case, it's misappropriated, but I need to use it as it is, so I get a ListItemCollection of all the "ID's" which come from a text table, but that's done, so I get this list with all the ID's and now I want to point to the specific ID.

Comment: You cannot establish a "real" foreign key relationship between e.g. SQL Server and Sharepoint - unless you'd extract those "IDs" and store them into a database table in your database

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I should create a table where I store the ID's of the Sharepoint data. Then is there also a way to update this table automatically when there is a change in the Sharepoint data?

Comment: IF you want to establish some kind of foreign key to ensure only valid ID's are used - yes, that's the only way I see that you could achieve this. The updating from Sharepoint is something you need to develop yourself - I don't think there's anything to do this automatically. Write a little tool to fetch the ID's via the Sharepoint REST API, store them into the table - and run this tool e.g. every day, every 4 hours - whatever your need is